# SurfaceController file edited by Kudu does not change the application content

Tags: asp.net, azure, umbraco, kudu

i have a problem with my application created in umbraco.

I have implemented the application on microsoft azure and I wanted to edit one function in the controller using kudu. I have edited the controller file, but the changes have not been made in the application (as I will go to the site is the state from before editing). I have combined a bit how to get the desired effect, I even deleted the controller file and it is still the same (state from before. Can you write to me how to correctly edit the controller file?

Comment: The reason you are not getting the updated piece of code as you have to make changes in the controller ,build the project and then update the DLL in KUDU to get the desired changes in your application. Let me know if you need any help further.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT only that I do not have a project on the computer that I am currently working on, and from what I understand I have to change the function in the controller later to build the application and then upload the controller file using kudu. Is there any way to get what i want without having an application project ?

Comment: Usually controller are code behind file which is included in a project. and while deploying we use the DLL's(dynamic link library) as a output. To change in a function of a controller you need to build the project file and replace the DLL in KUDU then only you will be able to see the changes.Hope it helped.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT ok so there is no way to achive what i want without having project of my application on my pc am i right ?

Comment: Yes There is no other way.

Comment: where is the controller file?  If it's sitting in the App_Code directory then you can probably edit it, and then just need to re-start the service.  The fact that you mention that you are editing the controller would suggest this is the case?